# jQuery .change event for array of elements

Tags: jquery

I have an array of drop-downs in a page, one for each row in a list of records.
I need to update a DIV's content in the row of the drop-down that triggers each change event.

Something like this:

```
<div class="price"></div>

<select id="plan[]" name="plan[]" class="sel">
  <option value="0" selected="selected">None</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>   


$(function() {
    $('#plan').change(function(){
        $(this).prevAll('.price:first').html('foo bar');
    });
});
```

The change event never fires, what am I missing? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8daeu/5/) to test

Comment: I'm assuming you've set `name="plan[]"` because it will eventually be submitted to a PHP script and needs to be an array.  You don't have to set `id="plan[]"` as PHP will not use it.  Just set `id="plan"` and your jQuery will work fine.

Comment: Yes, I need to submit it to a PHP script. So I can leave id="plan" and name="plan[]"? Didn't know that to be honest... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using startswith wild card with id selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySTFq/)**

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^=plan]').change(function(){
        $('.price:first').html('foo bar');
    });
});
```

If you have single item and do not need wild card you can do it with id selector like this.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ySTFq/2/)**

```
$(function () {
  $('[id="plan[]"]').change(function () {
    $(this).prev('.price').html('foo bar');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the id of your element is `plan[]` and not `plan` so the event callback is registered to no object.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` isn't `plan` it's `plan[]`.  `$("#plan[]")` should work as the selector, but it also seems like a mistake to me.  You probably want to change it to something else.  It also implies that there are multiple `plan[]` id elements on the page, which is invalid.